# show html tags from db into text area

Tags: html

There is some html text stored in the Database which I want to show in an html text area as it was in the Database.

Text in DB is:

```
<SPAN STYLE= "" >I should have known this....</SPAN>
```

but when I show it in the text area it gets displayed as:

```
I should have known this
</SPAN> 
">
```

I am filling the text area like so:

```
<textarea class="inputtext" name="content" value="<?=$row2['contentFull']?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a default value in a `TEXTAREA` you need to code it like this:

```
<textarea name="content"><?php echo $row2['contentFull']; ?></textarea>
```

It's because `TEXTAREA` does not have the `value` attribute nor is it a singular or unpaired tag like `INPUT`.  It is instead a paired tag. One where you have to have both the opening and a closing tag.

Make sure also that unless you want an extra line break showing, to have the start of your output right after the opening `TEXTAREA` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Because a textarea does not have a "value" attribute, you put the text between the opening and the closing tags:

```
<textarea class="inputtext" name="content">
<?=$row2['contentFull']?>
</textarea>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp